# How to read a file using rememberLauncherForActivityResult in Kotlin Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

So I have this composable which tries to read data from storage,

```
@Composable
private fun Screen() {
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val uri = result.data?.data.toString()
        if(uri !== null) {
            val file = File(uri)
            val bytes = file.readBytes()
            println(bytes)
        }
    }
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {
            val intent = Intent().setType("*/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
            launcher.launch(intent)
        }) {
            Text("Open file")
        }
    }
}
```

However, it gives me this error: `content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FIMG_CEFEFF486A8C-1.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out,

```
@Composable
private fun Screen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { result ->
        val item = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(result)
        val bytes = item?.readBytes()
        println(bytes)
        item?.close()
    }

    return Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            launcher.launch("*/*")
        }) {
            Text("Open file")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, if the `contract` is `CreateDocument` then the pre-defined file name should go into the parameter of `launcher.launch()`

Comment: Can we input a pre-defined path, so when the File Picker is opened it will open at the specified folder?

Comment: Ty @Axel u made my day! (ty android dev documentation.. that does not work well!)

Comment: I'm getting null for the result / uri.

Comment: Seems to happen on API > 29, and only when I use another program to pick a file.